# Database tables inner joining

Tags: java, database, user-interface, datatables

I'm looking to have a GUI where when I click an Invoice it displays the information from both Customer and Product also, such as name, brand etc all in one row.
Do I have to put Name, brand, etc into Invoice too and inner join everything?

[Invoice Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1f1KK.png)   [Customer Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMLiC.png)   [Product Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1uVH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

No, no need to modify the tables you're referring to. They all contain a unique primary key column which are referenced from the *invoice table*. Based on them the `INNER JOIN` can be formulated.

Maybe also worth mentioning: Don't confuse the `INNER JOIN` with the `SELF JOIN` which also exists.

The difference is that the `INNER JOIN` is still joining two different tables based on specific columns (e.g. id) whereby the `SELF JOIN` is joining a single table with itself.

---

Yes what you'll need is the `INNER JOIN` combining the information from your *invoice table* with the one from the *customer table* as well as the *product table* - all based on your given invoice id (column: **idInvoice**).

To obtain the needed information you don't need to add - and therefore repeat - it in the *invoice table*. Due to the join they'll be available for selection in one single query.

Your query should look like:

```
SELECT *
  FROM invoice inv, customer cust, product prod
WHERE
  inv.idCustomer = cust.idCostumer
AND
  inv.idProduct = prod.idProduct
AND
  inv.idInvoice = ${theIdOfTheInvoiceTheUserClickedOn}
```

**Note:** If you don't need all the information (columns) from the three tables (what the "*" stands for) you can replace the "*" with an enumeration explicitly stating only the columns you want to show. E.g. `inv.id, cust.FirstName, cust.LastName`.

Depending on the database technology/ dialect you're exactly using. The example above would be suitable for an `Oracle` database and should also suite most other databases, since only basic `SQL` features are being used in the query.

I'm assuming you're not using any *ORM framework* like `Hibernate` and that you'll need to write the query yourself (since you didn't provide any more detail on your technology stack). In case youre using an *ORM framework* the approach would need to look different, but the final generated query should look similar.

In the query above the first two conditions in the `WHERE clause` are forming the `INNER JOIN` implicitly, whereby the last third one is specifying which exact entry you're looking for.

Although you've asked only if an `INNER JOIN` is needed, I've provided the query here to you since your question implied you're not sure how to write one.

You might take it as an working example you can compare your solution with. You should try to understand how it's working and how it can be written and also research more on the `SQL` basics so that you can write it on your own as well.

**Tip**: *PreparedStatements* are the way to go to execute such queries to a database from `Java` in a safe way

Comment: I see, thanks for explaining that for me. I was a little confused as I managed to make a query and got the table I was looking for but I thought maybe perhaps I needed all of the same columns in the tables I was joining but cheers for clearing that up for me :)!

Comment: Sure, I'm glad I could help! Indeed SQL/ joining can be a bit confusing in the beginning, it also took me some time to get into it - just keep going! :) Also what can be added is that your design looks pretty well and it's common to design it like that - I'd do it the same in a real world application. Probably you might have heard of and are interested in "database normalizations". Your design looks already a lot like the 3rd form which usually is the best trade-off. Also I'd appreciate it a lot when you officially accept my answer when it could help resolve your question :)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, based on your application, you can use a flat table that includes what you need and doesn't need to join tables. This solution is applicable when you are in a situation that you have small datasets (E.g. in banking, relationships between `Terminal` table and `ATMTerminal`, `POSTerminal` and `CashlessTerminal` tables).

And for situations that you have a relationship that one side is static data (like the above example) and another side is transactional data (like **Banking Transactions**), you should use the foreign key from the transaction table to the static data table.

I recommend you to use the second solution for your problem and handle relationships using foreign keys and get the columns you need using the join strategy.